# Are there flaws in my Greedy algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, logic, greedy, proof

I was just wondering if you could see any flaws or problems with my Greedy algorithm I've come up with to solve this problem. The problem is:

- They're a set of employees
- Each employee has one work shift that is a single interval of time during the week. Shifts of employee's have the possibility of overlapping.
- A subset of the employees forms a Supervision group.
- The Supervision Group has a property that for every moment of every employee’s shift, there's a supervisor working as well.

Goal is to produce a Supervision Group whose size is as small as possible.

Now, my Greedy algorithm to solve this. 
Assume there's a list of employees:

```
  While(there are employee's who aren't supervisors and are not removed )
      Choose first employee working with longest work shift to be supervisor. 
      Remove any employee whos finish time is less than the current supervisor finish time.

      If(supervisor shift is ending)
         Turn employee whos shift interests with supervisor shift,
         with longest work time remaining into a supervisor as well.
      end if
  End while

      return list of supervisors
```

Will this work? And will this actually return the smallest group of supervisors possible? I'm not sure if this is the best way to be doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With each employee working exactly one shift, it is easy to prove that the greedy strategy produces an optimal solution.

Let's pretend that your algorithm does not produce an optimal solution. This means that there exists an employee `E0` who could replace at least two employees `E1` and `E2` who were assigned supervisors for two back-to-back intervals. This means that `E0`'s shift started at least as early as `E1`s, and ended as late or later that`E2`'s. If that were true, however, your greedy algorithm would have picked `E0` over `E1` to be the supervisor, which is a contradiction. This means that your algorithm finds an optimal solution to the problem.